# Using awk to merge 2 files

Tags: text-processing, awk, merge

I would like to merge 2 files based on column 1, 2, 3. I have tried the `awk` command below but is not working.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1FS$2FS$3]=$4; next}{k=$1FS$2FS$3; if (k in h) print $1,$2,$3,$4,h[k] ;else print $1,$2,$3,$4,"NA"}1' FS=\| OFS=\| file2.txt
```

file1.txt:

```
Student1|Class 1A|27|20140804 08:16:54
Student2|Class 1B|15|20140804 10:10:10
Student3|Class 1C|17|20140804 15:02:14
Student4|Class 1D|20|20140804 18:02:14
Student5|Class 2D|10|20140804 20:02:14
```

file2.txt:

```
Student1|Class 1A|27|20140805 08:16:54
Student2|Class 1B|15|20140805 10:10:10
Student4|Class 1D|20|20140805 18:02:14
Student5|Class 2D|10|20140805 20:02:14
```

Expected result:

```
Student1|Class 1A|27|20140804 08:16:54|20140805 08:16:54
Student2|Class 1B|15|20140804 10:10:10|20140805 10:10:10
Student3|Class 1C|17|20140804 15:02:14|NA
Student4|Class 1D|20|20140804 18:02:14|20140805 18:02:14
Student5|Class 2D|10|20140804 20:02:14|20140805 20:02:14
```

Comment: Drop the stray `1` at the end of the awk program, and give it `file2.txt` as the first file argument **and `file1.txt` as the second file argument**. Personally I'd also assume a nonancient awk and put `-vFS=\| -vOFS=\|` or just `-F\| -vOFS=\|` before the program instead of the vars-among-files method, and consider `$0` in place of `$1,$2,$3,$4`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Builds an array as with your example and just prints merged fields via `END { ... }`.

```
$ awk -F\| '{ k=$1 FS $2 FS $3; h[k] = (k in h) ? h[k]=h[k] FS $4 : $0 } END { for(x in h){printf "%s%s\n",h[x],(length(h[x])>38) ? "" : "|NA"}}' file1.txt file2.txt|sort
Student1|Class 1A|27|20140804 08:16:54|20140805 08:16:54
Student2|Class 1B|15|20140804 10:10:10|20140805 10:10:10
Student3|Class 1C|17|20140804 15:02:14|NA
Student4|Class 1D|20|20140804 18:02:14|20140805 18:02:14
Student5|Class 2D|10|20140804 20:02:14|20140805 20:02:14
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it is working

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1,$2,$3]=$4; next}{print $0,($1,$2,$3) in h?h[$1,$2,$3]:"NA"}' FS=\| OFS=\| file2.txt file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's safe to assume that the first file contains the full list of keys, i.e. students, you can simply do the appending for each record first. Then, during `END`, you'll need to [sort](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html) the keys, trim the appended values and back-fill the missing values with `"NA"`:

```
$ awk -F\| '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $3;r[k]=r[k] FS $4;c[k]++}
    END{n=asorti(r,s);
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            print s[i] substr(r[s[i]],1) (++c[s[i]] == ARGC ? "" : FS "NA")
        }
    }' file1.txt file2.txt
Student1|Class 1A|27|20140804 08:16:54|20140805 08:16:54
Student2|Class 1B|15|20140804 10:10:10|20140805 10:10:10
Student3|Class 1C|17|20140804 15:02:14|NA
Student4|Class 1D|20|20140804 18:02:14|20140805 18:02:14
Student5|Class 2D|10|20140804 20:02:14|20140805 20:02:14
```

I'm using `++c[s[i]] == ARGC`, where `ARGC` tells use the number of files + 1 (being the `awk` command itself), to do the back-fill comparison.